# What does "end to end with" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is the description of a wine corks jigsaw puzzle [on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002HY5VQ):

> Pop the cork on your favorite wine as you sit down to work on this challenging 1000-piece puzzle. **The corks end to end with their varying sizes**, shapes, and colors will test your puzzling skills! Be careful not to spill your glass if you get frustrated with this one!.

What does **end to end with** mean?

Comment: It is not a very well-written sentence.  The author is trying to cram a lot of information into one sentence and could have rearranged things a little to make the meaning clearer: *The corks, arranged end to end, will test your puzzling skills with their varying sizes, shapes, and colors.* or *Arranged end to end, the corks will test your puzzling skills with their varying sizes, shapes, and colors.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preposition "with" refers to "corks". It's used to describe the characteristics of them. It does not apply to "end to end".

According to the Free Dictionary

[**end to end**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/end+to+end)

> 1. Placed in a row, such that the ends of each item are touching

This idiom is used to describe how the corks are disposed in the puzzle. Rows of corks, each cork touching the following cork in the row.

You can remove that part and change a bit the punctuation, maybe this way you'll understand the whole phrase. Let forget the "end-to-end" part momentarily. What about?

> The corks - with their varying sizes, shapes, and colors - will test your puzzling skills!